# Why does python losing precision multiplying two big integers?

Tags: python

Why does python losing precision multiplying two big integers?

Consider these two random numbers:

```
>>> x = 924787625893878964793582
>>> y = 247625893
>>> z = x // y
>>> z
3734616015676030
>>> ###so to find x, we do: z*y, but getting wrong result
>>> z * y 
924787625893878927444790
```

### Update:

Isn't `z * y = x`, 
if    `z = x / y` ?

Why does Python give me the same result for two different operations:

```
>>> 924787625893878927444790 // 247625893
3734616015676030

>>> 924787625893878964793582 // 247625893
3734616015676030
```

Comment: Multiplication is fine. You've either misunderstood what `//` does or mistaken 9376672047376927764568475876093497876650845986349659662 for a multiple of 769408734659474654396738437683460980948676.

Comment: @user2357112 sorry, yeah, I've updated the numbers..Now they are producing integer when divided. Could you explain what's wrong there now? isn't `z * y = x` ?

Comment: Are you under the impression that 924787625893878964793582 is a multiple of 247625893?

Comment: `/` actually *will* lose precision, because it'll produce a float. If you want to check divisibility, use `%`.

Comment: @user2357112 I've updated the question, see how Python gives me the same result for 2 different operations, why is that? I guess that's what really bugs me. All of a sudden `x not equal y * z` when `z = x / y`

Comment: "Why does Python give me the same result for two different operations" - because the two operations have the same result. It's quite ordinary for different operations to have the same result. For example, 1+3 has the same result as 2+2.

Comment: @user2357112 right, but what I'm seeing above is similar to `11 / 2 = 5` and `10 / 2 = 5` and when I'm dividing one by another it gives me 1, which is not right

Answer (score 1):

You're using integer division, so the decimal portion is truncated. On line 3, use a single slash.

Comment: Your proposed fix actually *will* lose precision, because floating-point numbers have limited precision.